# SwiftData: How to model inheritance?

Tags: swift, swift-data

My model class includes an array of objects that have some properties in common and some specific to only a subset. That sounds like a use case for a `protocol` and inheritance. However, I can't get SwiftData to compile this.

Minimal example:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class Workout {
    var startTime: Date
    var endTime: Date?
    var activities: [Activity]
    
    init(startTime: Date, endTime: Date? = nil, activities: [Activity]) {
        self.startTime = startTime
        self.endTime = endTime
        self.activities = activities
    }
}

protocol Activity {
    var calories: Int {get}
}

@Model
class Run: Activity {
    var calories: Int
    var steps: Int
    
    init(calories: Int, steps: Int) {
        self.calories = calories
        self.steps = steps
    }
}

@Model
class Swim: Activity {
    var calories: Int
    var lanes: Int
    
    init(calories: Int, lanes: Int) {
        self.calories = calories
        self.lanes = lanes
    }
}
```

The error `Type 'any Activity' cannot conform to 'PersistentModel'` occurs in the generated code for the array:

[image]

I watched the WWDC videos, read through the docs and looked at all example projects I could find — nowhere is this problem tackled.

Does anyone have an idea either how to make SwiftData to support this *or* how to model the data in a compatible way?

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you come up with a solution/workaround?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Model
class Workout<T: Activity> {
    var startTime: Date
    var endTime: Date?
    var activities: [T]
    
    init(startTime: Date, endTime: Date? = nil, activities: [T]) {
        self.startTime = startTime
        self.endTime = endTime
        self.activities = activities
    }
}

protocol Activity: PersistentModel {
    var calories: Int {get}
}

@Model
class Run: Activity {
    var calories: Int
    var steps: Int
    
    init(calories: Int, steps: Int) {
        self.calories = calories
        self.steps = steps
    }
}

@Model
class Swim: Activity {
    var calories: Int
    var lanes: Int
    
    init(calories: Int, lanes: Int) {
        self.calories = calories
        self.lanes = lanes
    }
}
```

This might help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This approach is probably not what you want because it means all items in an activity must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm tackling this in my application: anything that needs to be "variant" (different depending on the type) is put into a struct that is enum'd upon. This isn't *great* because it means you can't filter/search on the variant properties, but it works:

```swift
@Model class Workout {
    var startTime: Date
    var endTime: Date?
    var activities: [Activity]
    
    init(startTime: Date, endTime: Date? = nil, activities: [Activity]) {
        // ...
    }
}

@Model class Activity {
    var calories: Int
    var activityType: ActivityType

    init(calories: Int, activityType: ActivityType) {
        // ...
    }
}

enum ActivityType: Codable {
    case swim(lanes: Int)
    case run(steps: Int)
}
```

There are a few things to note:

- You won't be able to query on a specific ActivityType
- If you use iCloud container sync, `Workout.activities`  will be unsorted. You'll need some kind of `order` property on activity to ensure ordering.